# Copying data from one Excel Worksheet to another using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a VLOOKUP table on one sheet and I require one column to be copied onto another sheet. Currently, I can get the data copied across but I would like it so that only certain rows are copied over on a condition.

=VLOOKUP(ALL_DATA!A2,ALL_DATA!A2:E20001,5,FALSE)

This is the formula I have currently. It works but when I drag it down, it copies all of the data. I want it so that I drag it down and it copies all of the data based on a condition. For example, copy all of the email addresses in column B where column A contains the value = CTP03. Is this possible?

Sheet 1 Test Data

```
CTP03   emailaddress
CTP03   emailaddress
CTP03   emailaddress
CTP04   emailaddress
```

Sheet 2 Expected Output

```
CTP03   emailaddress
CTP03   emailaddress
CTP03   emailaddress
```

The reason that I am looking for a formula is because the data changes weekly so I would like to copy and paste all of the data into sheet 1 which would then automatically populate sheet 2 with all of the email addresses for CTP03

Comment: please provide test data and expected output in the original post.

Comment: Test data and expected output added

Comment: `VLOOKUP` formula only returns the *first* instance of a match. This may be possible with a formula, but would be trivial to implement with a macro, or, if want a non-code/non-formula solution, just set the sheet's Filter to the "CTP03" value and copy the visible cells.

Comment: Thank you for your response but just using the Filter would not work in this instance. I am trying to just copy all data into one sheet which would then populate other sheets automatically so I believe that a formula is required. I used VLOOKUP as I thought this would work but do you know of a formula that would work for this?